# How to for_each over a map inside a map with strings based on workspace

Tags: foreach, terraform

I have variable like this:

```
variable "hosts" {
    type = map(map(string))
    default = {
      workspace1 = {
        hostname1-workspace1-1 = 177.104
        hostname1-workspace1-2 = 177.105
        hostname1-workspace1-3 = 177.106
    }
      workspace2 = {
        hostname1-workspace2-1 = 129.124
        hostname1-workspace2-2 = 129.125
        hostname1-workspace2-3 = 129.126
    }
    }
}
```

and I'm trying to for_each over this map, so I can create a VM NIC for each host in the map, but only for whatever workspace is selected.
Where each.key should be the name of the current workspace selected, and each.value should be the last 2 octets of the IP address based on the workspace  I tried something like this:

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "redis_vm_nic" {
    for_each = var.hosts[terraform.workspace]
    name                        = "${each.key}VMNic"
    location                    = "${var.redis_rg_location[terraform.workspace]}"
    resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.infrastructure_redis_rg.name
    ip_configuration {
        name                          = "ipconfig${each.key}"
        subnet_id                     = var.aks_subnet
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
        private_ip_address = "10.99.${each.value}"
    }
    tags =  var.tags_vms
}
```

but I get:

```
│
│   on main.tf line 59, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine":
│   59:     network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.redis_vm_nic[each.key].id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.redis_vm_nic is object with 3 attributes
│     │ each.key is "workspace1"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 59, in resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine":
│   59:     network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.redis_vm_nic[each.key].id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ azurerm_network_interface.redis_vm_nic is object with 3 attributes
│     │ each.key is "workspace2"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
```

Comment: What is azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is certainly not in `azurerm_network_interface`. You are iterating correctly on the sub-map. I think the problem is with how you do the `for_each` in `azurerm_linux_virtual_machine`. From what I see in the error, the `for_each` for the Linux VM is probably in this format:

```
for_each = var.hosts
```

You most like would want to have it as it is in the `azurerm_network_interface`, so:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine" {
  for_each = var.hosts[terraform.workspace]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct that was the issue.  After adding the workspace specification to the other resources that required it further down the recipe everything worked perfectly.  Thanks!